# The most pleasant cities to stay in Ireland, other than Dublin?

Tags: ireland, cities

I am an EU citizen and I'd like to spend a year or more in Ireland. I don't need to look for a job there, as I work online.

I have never been to The Emerald Isle and I'd rather not to stay in Dublin (as it is the most costly, as far as I know). I don't want to stay in remote villages either. It would be too boring and I don't want to be the only foreigner around.

So what cities would you suggest, where people and places are generally pleasant, accommodation is affordable, crime rates are low and expats are not unheard of?

Comment: @pnuts +1 I was about to suggest Cork too. Great town.

Comment: @pnuts thanks for your point. Didn't know about the expat forum. I'll definitely ask the question there.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Please note that this is not a traditional discussion forum, but a Q&A site with specific guidelines for participation; it is off-topic to solicit opinions ("most pleasant") or to ask about long-term relocation ("a year or more") here.  I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Our sister site for [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest (but please read their rules as well before posting).

Comment: Like @choster points out though, both travel and expats are Q&A sites, not for soliciting opinions :/ As it stands it's like to be closed on both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Galway is a great place to visit and stay.

In the beautiful West of Ireland and with a strong tradition of music and the arts.

City wise it is one of the nicest to go to in the country.

Comment: I don't live there at the moment
It would have a lot of tourism
There was also a lot of people from the EU and other countries working there a few years ago
Like anywhere in Ireland there will be a few expats, especially British and some Americans but whether there's enough to constitute a community is debatable